# Programmatically access orientation of an iPhone video

Tags: iphone, objective-c, video, orientation

I need to access a video returned by the UIImagePickerController and know if it was recorded portrait or landscape. I've seen references to mov_read_tkhd but I'm not sure if that will do the job, or indeed how to include the necessary libraries.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On iOS 4 and above, with 3GS/3rd gen iTouch or better, you can use the new AVFoundation libraries.

Something like:

```
NSURL *url = // url to the video returned by the picker
AVAssetTrack *videoTrack = [[url tracksWithMediaType:AVMediaTypeVideo] objectAtIndex:0];
videoTrack.preferredTransform; // CGAffineTransform that tells you whether the video is rotated from original orientation
videoTrack.naturalSize; // CGSize that tells you the current dimensions of the video
```

Comment: Thanks - this question was asked a little before iOS4 was out, but I appreciate the response. I don't think it was possible in iOS3: I never managed it anyway.

Comment: No worries - I came across this searching, and once we'd solved it I thought it worth filling in in case someone else finds it :)