# Detect orientation of an iPhone video from server

Tags: php, video, orientation

I am attempting to detect the orientation of an iPhone video file (.mov) on upload through a PHP form so that I can use FFMPEG to correct it (a lot of the videos uploaded are shown on their side). I can not seem to find a way of accessing the orientation of the uploaded file on the server. Any ideas?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2814626/programatically-access-orientation-of-an-iphone-video

Comment: @craig1231 Huh? So, since a browser is a client it shouldn't be allowed to interact with the server running PHP?  The iPhone certainly can [send requests, and data, to a webserver](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3249897/get-content-of-webservice).

Comment: Sorry, just clarified the question, the user uploads the file from their pc via a html/php form

Comment: You need to detect the orientation on the client (iPhone) then send that to the server and have php talk to ffmpeg

Comment: @CharlesSprayberry PHP itself is not a webserver

Comment: @craig1231 Of course it isn't.  But to say that a client can't interact with or send data to PHP is disingenuous.  If the client had no way of sending data to PHP then PHP-powered websites wouldn't even exist.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Using mediainfo

```
$ mediainfo test.mp4 | grep Rotation
Rotation                         : 90°
```

You can use exec() to capture the output of this system call, and apply the orientation fix (90 degrees clockwise):

```
$ ffmpeg -i test.mp4 -vf "transpose=1" testRotated.mp4
```

If you have --enable_vfilters

```
$ ffmpeg -vfilters "rotate=90" -i test.mp4 testRotated.mp4
```

Comment: yea but that is assuming it was recorded on portrait

Answer (score 0):

I'm not the best with regex but here is how I would go about doing it

```
exec(ffmpeg -i uploaded.mov,$output)
```

Then once you have the output do a pregmatch on it, like so

```
preg_match('/(\d+)x(\d+)/', $output, $dims);
```

Then check to see if $dims[1] is greater than $dims[2], if it is then it's in landscape, if it's less than its in portrait.

I wasn't able to test it fully but something along those lines should work for you.

Comment: Dimensions tell you nothing about the orientation. It might work in some cases but not if you turn the camera upside down or the camera using portrait normally.